# Redirecionar antes de logar no sistema - Angular

Tags: angular

Tenho uma tela de login, com a total “/authentication/login”.

Como fazer no angular quando o usuário entrar no sistema, ele vai direto para esta rota ?

Após logar se ele digitar esta rota, ele sempre valida e se o usuário tiver logado ele vai para a rota “/” ?

**Rota**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { FullComponent } from './layouts/full/full.component';
import { AppBlankComponent } from './layouts/blank/blank.component';

export const AppRoutes: Routes = 
[
  {
    path: '',
    component: FullComponent,
    children: 
    [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './dashboards/dashboards.module#DashboardsModule'  
        /*pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: '/dashboards/dashboard1', */
      },
      {
        path: 'configuracao',
        loadChildren: './paginas/configuracao/configuracao.module#ConfiguracaoModule'  
      },
      {
        path: 'arquivo',
        loadChildren: './paginas/arquivo/arquivo.module#ArquivoModule'  
      },
      {
        path: 'declaracao',
        loadChildren: './paginas/declaracao/declaracao.module#DeclaracaoModule'  
      },
      {
        path: 'parametro',
        loadChildren: './paginas/parametro/parametro.module#ParametroModule'  
      },
      {
        path: 'endereco',
        loadChildren: './paginas/endereco/endereco.module#EnderecoModule'  
      },
      {
        path: 'contribuinte',
        loadChildren: './paginas/banco/banco.module#BancoModule'  
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: './dashboards/dashboards.module#DashboardsModule'  
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppBlankComponent,
    children: 
    [
      {
        path: 'authentication',
        loadChildren: './authentication/authentication.module#AuthenticationModule'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '404' 
  }
];
```

Versão do angular: **5.0.0**

Comment: qual versão do `angular`? Pode seu código de rotas?

Comment: Incluído na pergunta principal

Comment: Ao definir `path: ''` isso quer dizer que será sua rota padrão. Porque não adicionar seu componente na rota padrão?

Comment: Então foi me passado o projeto desta forma. Qual seria a diferença ?

Neste projeto que estou trabalhando, tem as rotas e subrotas. Cada subrota é chamado no seu módulo.

Answer (score 0):

**Fiz assim e assim resolveu.**

**CanActivateAuthGuard**

> ```
> import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
> import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
> import { AuthenticationService } from '../servico/authentication/authentication.service';
>
> @Injectable()
> export class CanActivateAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
>
>   constructor(
>     private router: Router, 
>     private authService: AuthenticationService
>   ) {}
>
>   canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
>     if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
>       return true;
>     }
>     this.router.navigate(['/authentication/login']);
>     return false;
>   }
> }
> ```

**Rotas seguras**

> ```
> import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
> import { ArquivoComponent } from './arquivo/arquivo.component';
> import { ArquivoFormComponent } from './arquivo-form/arquivo-form.component';
> import { CanActivateAuthGuard } from '../../authentication/can-activate.authguard';
>
> export const ArquivoRoutes: Routes = [
>   {
>     path: '',
>     children: [
>       {
>         path: '',
>         component: ArquivoComponent,
>         canActivate: [CanActivateAuthGuard] 
>       }
>       , {
>         path: 'novo',
>         component: ArquivoFormComponent,
>         canActivate: [CanActivateAuthGuard] 
>       }
>     ]
>   }
> ];
> ```

**AuthenticationService**

> import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
>       import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
>       import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
>       import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
>       import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
>       import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
>
> ```
> import { Usuario } from '../../modelo/usuario/usuario.model';
> import { BASE_AUT_URL } from '../base-api-url-defaul';
>
> @Injectable()
> export class AuthenticationService {
>
>     private base: string;
>     private options: Function;
>
>     private headers = new Headers({
>         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
>         'Accept': 'application/json',
>         'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
>         'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
>     });
>
>     constructor(private http: Http) {
>         this.base = BASE_AUT_URL
>     }
>
>     login(usuario: Usuario): Observable<boolean> {
>         console.log(this.headers);
>         return this.http.post(this.base, JSON.stringify({login: usuario.login, senha: usuario.senha}), {headers: this.headers})
>             .map((response: Response) => {
>                 let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
>                 if (token) {
>                     localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: usuario.login, token: token }));
>                     localStorage.setItem('token', token);
>                     localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(usuario.login));
>                     localStorage.setItem('usuario', response.json().usuario);
>                     localStorage.setItem('nomeUsuario', response.json().nomeUsuario);
>                     localStorage.setItem('grupoUsuario', response.json().grupo);
>                     return true;
>                 } else {
>                     return false;
>                 }
>             }
>         ).catch(
>             (error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')
>         );
>     }
>
>     getToken(): String {
>         //var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
>         //var token = currentUser && currentUser.token;
>         var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
>         return token ? token : "";
>     }
>
>     logout(): void {
>         localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
>         localStorage.removeItem('token');
>         localStorage.removeItem('user');
>         localStorage.removeItem('usuario');
>         localStorage.removeItem('nomeUsuario');
>         localStorage.removeItem('grupoUsuario');
>     }
>
>     isLoggedIn(): boolean {
>         var token: String = this.getToken();
>         return token && token.length > 0;
>     }
> }
> ```

usei como referência esse artigo: [Angular Authentication: Using Route Guards](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3)

Answer (score 0):

Já fiz isso uma vez, fiz dessa maneira usando redirectTo e pathMatch -

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { EventosComponent } from './pages/eventos/eventos/eventos.component';
import { EventosCadastroComponent } from './pages/eventos/eventos-cadastro/eventos- 
cadastro.component';
import { AuthComponent } from './pages/auth/auth.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './shared/utils/auth.guard';


const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', redirectTo: '/auth', pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent }
];
```